# how to do logging in asp.net application IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, logging

i have a asp.net web application written about 2 years ago .It does not have any logging mechanism in it. Ideally I would like to log any errors that happen especially at the database level. I cannot afford to break the application however, and I have limited time.

I have heard about **ELMAH**. Is it possible to have something that doesn't talk to my code directly and just does its own thing by monitoring the server?

- It was made in ASP.NET 3.5.
- It has AJAX as well as heavy use of ViewState.
- The application also communicates with Excel.
- It is built in Visual Studio 2008 w/ SQL Server 2005 on the backend.

How do I go about deploying this website with above requirements?

Comment: Is the event viewer not sufficient, or are the errors handled without any sort of logging?

Comment: the errors are handled ,but there is no logging to know what happened where ,how and why ?

Comment: If the errors are handled and no exceptions are thrown, I think you'll have to build logging into the application.

Comment: thanks to everyone for help and advice ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Added ELAMH to your application - it will log the errors. It's non-invasive.

Once ELMAH is added to your application it hooks into the OnError Event and captures all errors throw by your application. This is assuming that your application does not swallow the errors.

The documentation around [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is through and easy to follow.

Comment: Do you have a helpful link to share as well?

Comment: will it log if there is a failed transaction in the database ?do I have to do something to hook it up with the database errors ?

Comment: I get the impression that the exceptions are being swallowed.

Comment: @ashutoshraina if the exception is throw and not swallowed in a catch statement then yes, it will log the error.

Answer (score 2):

There is also log4net -

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: At minimum you would need to make changes to your web.config and/or global.asax Application_Error()